# elasticsearch - Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/] and method [PUT], allowed: [DELETE, GET, HEAD]

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my JSON data.

```
"{\"athena\":{\"settings\":{\"index\":{\"max_ngram_diff\":\"49\",\"mapping\":{\"total_fields\":{\"limit\":\"3000\"},\"ignore_malformed\":\"true\"},\"refresh_interval\":\"30s\",\"number_of_shards\":\"1\",\"max_shingle_diff\":\"4\",\"max_result_window\":\"100000\",\"analysis\":{\"filter\":{\"searchkick_index_shingle\":{\"token_separator\":\"\",\"type\":\"shingle\"},\"analyzed_ngram\":{\"token_chars\":[\"letter\",\"digit\"],\"min_gram\":\"2\",\"type\":\"edge_ngram\",\"max_gram\":\"10\"},\"location_synonym_filter\":{\"type\":\"synonym\",\"synonyms\":[\"e=>east\",\"w=>west\",\"n=>north\",\"s=>south\",\"rd=>road\",\"st=>street\",\"av=>avenue\",\"pkwy=>parkway\",\"hwy=>highway\"]},\"searchkick_stemmer\":{\"type\":\"snowball\",\"language\":\"English\"}},\"char_filter\":{\"ampersand\":{\"type\":\"mapping\",\"mappings\":[\"&=> and \"]}},\"normalizer\":{\"lowercase_normalizer\":{\"filter\":[\"lowercase\"],\"type\":\"custom\"}},\"analyzer\":{\"searchkick_index\":{\"filter\":[\"lowercase\",\"asciifolding\",\"searchkick_index_shingle\",\"searchkick_stemmer\"],\"char_filter\":[\"ampersand\"],\"type\":\"custom\",\"tokenizer\":\"standard\"},\"autocomplete_analyzer\":{\"filter\":[\"lowercase\",\"location_synonym_filter\"],\"token_chars\":[\"letter\",\"digit\"],\"type\":\"custom\",\"stopwords\":\"_none_\",\"tokenizer\":\"standard\"}}},\"number_of_replicas\":\"0\"}}}}"
```

and I am running this command.

```
elasticdump --input=./athena-analyzer.json --output=http://localhost:9200 --type=analyzer
```

and i am getting this error.

{"error":"Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/] and method [PUT], allowed: [DELETE, GET, HEAD]","status":405}

Comment: what are you trying to do with elasticdump?

Comment: trying to import athena-analyzer